# Using SAX with JAVA ServerSocket Class

Tags: java, xml, sockets, sax, serversocket

I am going to build a very simple instant messenger based on JAVA.

I had decided to use XML & SAX to communicate between server and client.

(I think it will be a good practive for my andriod programming skill. That's why I choose.)

I am trying to use XMLReader, ServerSocket and BufferedReader class.

But, when I googled to find out any resouces or examples to implement them, I couldn't find.

Does anyone can show me an example or tell me how can I implement it?

It would be highly appreciated to let me know if there is any other better way.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question? other than requesting an implementation?

Answer (score 0):

As a hint, you might want to consider using `SAXParser` instead of `XMLReader`.

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
saxParser.parse(socket.getInputStream(), handler);
```

(where `socket` is what is returned by ServerSocket, and `parser` is your custom SAX Handler, which processes your incoming XML)

As an aside, while you didnt mention it specifically, if you wanted to use XML to communicate with instant messenger server & client, you might want to look into [XMPP](http://xmpp.org), which is an open standard (XML) protocol for IM communication.

Comment: Thank you very much Crollster!! Have a great day! :)